# Why does Swapneshwari Devi give us seemingly nonsensical dreams?

Tags: scripture, devi

Lots of dream meanings are given in Hinduism but some dreams are just pure nonsense! So who is giving Swapneshwari Devi the order to give these dreams and with what objective?

Why does she send messages in this manner?

Comment: Are all dreams controlled by Swapaneswari Devi or only those which we get when we are doing her Sadhana?